# Checking for a null DataRow

Tags: .net

How would I check for a null datetime value in a DataRow?

The following works with a dataReader.

```
calEventDTO.endTime = dr.IsDBNull(9) ? null : (DateTime?) dr.GetDateTime(9);
```

What is the equivalent when checking the following DataRow?

```
calEventDTO.endTime = (DateTime)row["endTime"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Convert.IsDBNull:

```
calEventDTO.endTime = (DateTime?) (Convert.IsDBNull(row["endTime"]) ? null : row["endTime"]);
```

Comment: This worked with a little adjustment (added (DateTime?)) that ReSharper found for me.
calEventDTO.recurrenceID = Convert.IsDBNull(row["recurrenceID"]) ? (DateTime?) null : (DateTime)row["recurrenceID"];

Comment: Yeah... I used your first snippet (which does not cast) as a base to mine. I've updated mine putting a cast on the result of the expression instead of casting each of the operands of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
calEventDTO.endTime = row["endTime"] != null ? (DateTime)row["endTime"] : null;
```

or even better

```
calEventDTO.endTime = row["endTime"] as DateTime;
```

PS. I'm assuming you are using C#, since you have not given any details about the language.

Comment: You can't use the `as` operator with DateTime since it is a value type, and the `as` operator can be used only with reference types.